# AT90USB1286 bricks after disabling clock divider

Tags: avr, atmel, avrdude, isp, fuse-bits

I have an AT90USB1286 which is connected to a 16MHz external crystal oscillator. It is my understanding that by default from the factory the CKDIV fuse is enabled which makes the chip run at an effective clock rate of 2MHz in my configuration. I used engbedded and left everything else as is, only disabling "Divide clock by 8 internally; [CKDIV8=0]". I programmed the following fuses:

`-U lfuse:w:0xc0:m -U hfuse:w:0x99:m -U efuse:w:0xff:m`

using my ISP and `avrdude` reported that the operation was successful. Unfortunately, I am no longer able to communicate with the chip over USB, and when attempting any operation using an ISP, the programmed reads a device signature of 0. Am I misunderstanding the purpose of this fuse? Is there some other dependent fuse that also needs to be changed?

Comment: The fuse settings you are using are for an external clock, not just putting a crystal (and caps) at the xtal pins.  Look at the other fuse settings.  If you have a function generator, you may be able to get it going by applying an appropriate frequency at those pins.  Look at section 7.2 and table 7-1 in your datasheet.

Comment: I believe you should check what evildemonic said. Also, are you using 5V or 3.3V as the MCU core supply voltage?

Comment: @Justme I am using 5V as the supply voltage.

Comment: @evildemonic I unfortunately do not have access to a function generator. I am a bit confused though, is a crystal and a couple of caps not sufficient? Section 7 in my datasheet is about ordering information...

Comment: That sounds like the summary datasheet. Look at [the complete one](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/doc7593.pdf) instead.

Comment: @00728M It is, however, you are not using the correct fuse setting for that.  The setting you are using is for when you inject your own clock signal into those pins.  It sounds like you are trying to use a low-power-crystal-oscillator.  Look at the other clock sources in the datasheet for clarity.

Comment: Hint:  Your CKSEL3..1 should likely be 111 (see Table 7-3)

Comment: @Finbarr thanks for pointing me there. From the datasheet: 

The default fuse configuration is CKSEL = "1110", SUT = "01", CKDIV8 = "0". 

whereas it looks like I programmed CKSEL=0000 which denotes a generic "external clock" whereas 1110 denotes 8.0+ MHz external crystal oscillator. I'll give this a try!

Comment: Here are the recommended fuse settings for AT90USB1286 with a 16MHz external crystal oscillator:

-U lfuse:w:0xDE:m -U hfuse:w:0x99:m -U efuse:w:0xF4:m

Comment: If you have no function generator, you can generate clock, for example, by PWM of Arduino, if you have any. Then try set right fuses and connect crystal back.